# How to combine two different tables from SQLite and PostgreSQL?

Tags: java, postgresql, sqlite

I am facing problem in combining two tables from different database queries in JAVA.
I have 2 tables A and B. A belongs to SQLite DB and B belongs to a Postgres DB.

Is there a way to combine these two tables and get the output.

I tried joining these tables from inner join query but its not working for me.

Table A belongs to sqlite DB

```
  appid |  charid
  ------+--------
  2142  |      2
  2142  |      4
  2142  |      7
```

Table B belongs to Postgres DB

```
charid  |          charname
--------+----------------------------
      1 | Bandwidth
      2 | Prone to misuse
      3 | Transfer files
      4 | Tunnels apps
```

I have to show output as below:

```
  appid |          charname
--------+----------------------------
   2142 | Excessive Bandwidth
   2142 | Prone to misuse
   2145 | Transfer files
   2146 | Tunnels other apps
```

Answer (score 2):

You cannot access multiple databases across JDBC drivers in a single query.

You must do two queries and merge them together yourself in your own code.

If this is a long term solution consider copying static tables across database. Perhaps even consolidate in a single database.

Answer (score 1):

If the tables aren't too big, the easiest solution is probably to do the join inside your Java code.

*If* you can put the SQLite database on Postgres server, you could try to install the [SQLite foreign data wrapper](https://github.com/gleu/sqlite_fdw) and create a [foreign table](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-createforeigntable.html) that makes the SQLite table available from inside Postgres.

Again: this requires that the SQLite database file can be moved to the Postgres server's file system.

Then you can join both tables in a single query against the Postgres server.

---

But maybe putting everything into a single database (e.g. Postgres) is the better solution in the long run.

Comment: is it possible to create a db-link from postrges to sqlite? https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/contrib-dblink-connect.html

Comment: @Chris: no, DbLink is only for connections to other Postgres servers

Comment: thx. i just thought so, im neither familiar with postgres nor sqlite

Answer (score -3):

I think you should create a view to combine the two tables using query like that :

```
`CREATE VIEW [dbo].[YourView]
 as
 select 
 a.charId, 
 a.SomeInfo, 
 b.SomeOtherInfo
 from TableInA a
join DatabaseB.dbo.TableInB b ..`
```

after that you can query the view

Comment: A view over tables in two different databases?

Comment: why not? it's possible to do that

Comment: The question is about Postgres and SQLite, not about Microsoft SQL Server.